# CF7 jquery custom text on submit

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a simple radio button on CF7

```
[radio radio-698 id:domanda2 use_label_element default:1 "0.Nessuna Risposta" "risposta1" "risposta2"]
[submit "Invia"]
```

I want to display text "Hello Word" by jquery when button submit is pressed, but this code doesn't work - can you help me, please?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
    var val1 = $('#domanda2').val();
    if (val1 == '0.Nessuna Risposta' || val1 == 'risposta1' || val1 == 'risposta2') {
      $(field1).text("Hello world!");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Does CF7 = WordPress Contact form 7 ?  (added tags in-case it does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few simple issues with your jQuery. This should work for you assuming that there is an item with selector `#field1`.

Note, you can't get the value of an input in a radio or checkbox without specifying that it's the `:checked` one.

```
jQuery( function ($) {
    $(document).on( 'click','.wpcf7-submit', function (e) {
        let val1 = $('#domanda2 input:checked').val();
        if (val1 === '0.Nessuna Risposta' || val1 === 'risposta1' || val1 === 'risposta2') {
            $('#field1').text("Hello world!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, i have changed only row `$('#field1').text("Hello world!");`